# Bootstrap full width dropdown menu issue

Tags: css, menu

I am trying to me a Bootstrap dropdown menu to be fullscreen when open.
I have managed to do that with several ways, but when I move the mouse out of the menu to close it, a smaller menu appears behind my full-width.

Can you spot where is that and remove it?

https://www.suug.co.uk/sustainabilityhub/

Fullscreen code:

```css
.nav > li.dropdown.open {
    position: static;
}

.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    display: table;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: how about you create a fiddle for the codes used for your specific query. try to make the question as minimal as possible instead of sharing the whole site, so that it will be easier to debug

Comment: Can you add the dropdown markup too?

Comment: Please don't link to the external site since it will change over time and no longer be relevant for the question. Post the problem code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to work perfect, but i dont want to have to top:77px

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 77px; /*height of main menu*/
  width: 100%
}
```